# sscanf assigns wrong values in C

Tags: c, scanf

i am fairly new to C and i am facing an issue when i try to read some values using sscanf. The problem is sscanf reads all values properly **except** when the value of int i am trying to read is something like 08 or 00043, it starts with zero and it is followed by number.
This is the code i am using

```
Mystruct* readme(char const* input) {
    int value1;
    char value2[CONST_LENGTH];
    sscanf(input, "%*s %i %s", &value1, value2);
    return anotherfunction(value1, value2);
}
```

so when the input is something like this
    data 08 data

what i get is **value1=0** and **value2=8**

other examples in the format of input -> output

```
data 098 data2 -> what i get is **value1=0** and **value2=88** 
data 0007474 data2 -> what i get is **value1=3900** and **value2=data2** 
data 08787 data2 -> what i get is **value1=0** and **value2=8787** 
data 001212 data2 -> what i get is **value1=650** and **value2=data2**
```

thank you for any assistance you might be able to offer

Comment: @user3121023 it does not fail, it sees `08` and stops after the `0`, because `8` is not a valid octal digit. So it sets `value1` to 0, because that is what is in the string.

Comment: `scanf doesn't work as expected` is practically a tautology, and forms of that phrase ought not be used at question titles.

Comment: Check return value of sscanf (always) so you notice parse errors.

Comment: @user3121023  i did not think of this at all, you are right, after i set it as >%d it worked properly

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  You don't check the return value at all.

Comment: "data 098 data2 -> what i get is **value1=0** and **value2=88** " is this really true?  Review the `098` part and the `value2=88` part.